# How to get a list of methods defined in a subclass in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Let's say I have some ruby code like this:

```
class ParentClass
   def method1
     # some code
   end
end

class MyAwesomeSubclass < ParentClass
  def method1
    # some code
  end

  def method2
    # more code
  end
end
```

Is there a way to get a list of method defined on the subclass, so `[:method1, :method2]` in this example?  My first impulse was to say `MyAwesomeSubclass.methods - ParentClass.methods`, but this would remove `:method1` since method1 is defined on the parent class also.  I need a list of all methods that are defined by a subclass.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `MyAwesomeSubclass.instance_methods(false)`? I believe that's what you're looking for...

Comment: Yep, and here's the docs: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods